# React - How to make a call to web api to check username is valid?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, react-forms

I have a log in page (code below) it asks for a username to log in, I have tried adding checks to ensure the length is 7 (the length of any user in my database) and that only number are entered and not letters. However I would now like to make a call to my web api to check the username entered is valid but im not sure how to do this, can anyone please help?

In my API I have a get all usernamers method and a get user/ method

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Login.css";

export default function LogIn() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const regexp = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
  

  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (!regexp.test(value)) {
      alert("Username should not contain letters, please re-enter");

      return;
    }

    return history.replace("/UserWelcome", value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="Login">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Log into our Messaging Service</h1>
          <label>
            Username:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="UserId"
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
              maxLength="7"
              minLength="7"
            />
          </label>
          <button>Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean using `fetch`?

Comment: Yes, im not sure where in the code it would sit in, elsewhere I have it in componentDidMount() but I dont have that in this file so I have confused myself. Previously i have used this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = "<my api url>";
        fetch(proxyurl + url) 
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false })); with data and loading being set in a constructor but again i don't have that in this file, sorry if this is a very beginner question I'm new

Comment: You are placing code in comment and is no longer readable could you re-edit your quiz adding the code

Answer (score 1):

1. Fetch the data in  useEffect

[How to make  a get request in  useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

2. Filter the response data with the input value  using filter, includes, or indexOf method
3. Validate  value  if true

[How to use filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[How to use indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[How to use includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)